# when starting react native appear 5 high severity vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

when starting react native appear
5 high severity vulnerabilities
[image]

npm audit fix --force doesn't solve the problem

I tried to reinstall node.js, 5 vulnerabilities remained as they were
I tried reinstalling React Native, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those always used to scare me, too. I fixed it by switching to Yarn.

Comment: that sounds like an ostrich solution